# Find the solutions for $z,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ for $\sum^n_{i=1}u_{x_i}+|x|^2u^2(x)=0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $c(x,z)=|x|^2\cdot z^2$, and $b(x,z)=(1,1,\ldots,1),~U\subset \mathbb{R}^2,~\Gamma \subset \partial U$ and $u(x)=g(x)$ on $\Gamma$.  If $\sum^n_{i=1}u_{x_i}+|x|^2u^2(x)=0$, then find the solutions for $z,x_1,x_2,\ldots$

Attempt:
$\sum^2_{i=1}u_{x_i}+|x|^2u^2(x)=0$ implies that $u_{x_1}+u_{x_2}+|x|^2u^2(x)=0$.   Since $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $u(x)$ is quasilinear equation and has the form $F(\Delta u,u,x)=b(x,u(x))\cdot\Delta u(x)=c(x,u(x))=0$.   I know I must obtain some characteristic equations for the quasilinear PDE:

(i) $\dot{x}(s)=b(x(s),z(s))$

(ii) $\dot{z}(s)=-c(x(s),z(s))$

But I am failing to succeed.

Comment: The characteristics can be deduced from the equalities $$\frac{dx_{1}}{1} = \frac{dx_{2}}{1} = \dots = \frac{dx_{n}}{1} = \frac{du}{- \lvert x \rvert^{2} u^{2}}$$

Comment: Solve what for $z$? The only thing you've given that involves a $z$ is the definitions of $c$ and $b$, neither of which occur in the rest of your problem statement. I suppose $x_i$ are the coordinates of $x$, so $x\in \Bbb R^n$? What about $z$? what sort of thing is it? But wait, $u(x) = g(x)$ on a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Does that mean $n = 2$? If not, how do you reconcile these two statements?